# byte byteVar = 100 works but int intVar = 100L results in compilation error. Why?

Tags: java

Integer literals can be assigned to byte or short variables **as long as the value of the literal is within the range of byte/short**.

But when long literal is assigned to int variable, **compilation error is reported even when the value of long literal is within the range of int**.

What is the logic explaining this?

Example,

The below line gets compiled successfully

```
byte byteVar =  100;   //works, here 100 is integer literal.
```

but

```
int intVar = 100L;   // fails, here 100L is long literal
```

results in compile time error.

Can someone please explain the underlying logic that drives this.

Comment: `even when the value of long literal is within the range of int.` No, long (64b) is larger than int (32b) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: `int intVar = 100L;  ` will never compile. You need  to declare it as a long type. You cannot stuff a 64-bit long into a 32-bit int.

Comment: The second assignment is a narrowing conversion from a long to an int, so needs an explicit cast according the the JLS. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html.

Comment: I think the author wants to know why is it that the compiler doesn't understand that the constant 100L fits into an int without losing information. I suppose they know about Java type promotions and when there's a need to cast because information will be lost such as from double to long when there's decimal places. I think it's an interesting question especially because 100L is constant and can't change.

Comment: @Fred just a decision of Java's designers.

Answer (score 2):

The actual reason is a bit more complicated than some of the other answers suggest.

[JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) states the following about the conversions allowed in an *assignment context*.

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
> type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is
>   representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the variable is of type `Byte`, `Short`, or `Character`, and
>   the value of the constant expression is representable in the type
>   `byte`, `short`, or `char` respectively.

The declaration / initialization

```
byte byteVar =  100;  // OK
```

works because all of the prerequisites are safisfied:

- `100` is a constant expression
- its type is `int`
- its value is in the range of `byte`; i.e. it is representable as a `byte`
- it is being assigned to a `byte` variable.

The declaration / initialization

```
byte byteVar =  100L;  // FAIL
```

fails because the type of `100L` is `long` rather than `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The logic for

```
int intVar = 100L;
```

not compiling is simply "why would you say `L` explicitly if you want it to be `int`? Probably a mistake somewhere, but we don't know if it's the type or the value which is wrong".

The more interesting part is why

```
byte byteVar = 100;
```

compiles instead of requiring you to write something like `100b`. And I believe there are at least two reasons:

1. the right part may be a constant expression, not just a literal: in

   ```
   byte byteVar = SOME_CONST + 3;
   ```

   you couldn't use a suffix, and the right-hand side is `int` even if `SOME_CONST` is `byte`.
2. simply that C++ didn't have it and Java inherited a lot from C++.

Answer (score 0):

`L` means 64-bit int integer primitive.

`int intVar = 100L;`

The following line will fail to compile because you are trying to place a 64-bit long primitive literal into a 32-bit int variable. It will give : // BAD — compiler fails — Cannot place a 64-bit `long` `int` primitive in a 32-bit `int` variable.

Comment: If that was the entire reason, `byte byteVar =  100;` wouldn't work either. The question is _why the difference_.

Comment: If this is the reason then why does int literal (of 32b) could go inside byte variable (of 8b)?

Comment: Just to clear the confusion, In Java byte range is `-128` to `127`. You can store integer within that range in a byte without overflowing. So, byte byteVar =  100; will work, but if you try : `byte byteVar =  128;` It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The byte format is an 8-bit integer format that can accept signed integer values in the range -128 to 127. Because the integer value 100 fits within this range,

```
byte byteVar = 100;
```

compiles; the integer literal is of a valid scale for what you are trying to store it in. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html lists default values for the primitive data types and the table shows that byte, short and int all share the same value structure; an integer with nothing else associated to the literal.

The reason the int and 100L does not work is because the L suffix creates a long or Int64 literal. int is Int32, the 32-bit 2's complement signed integer format. By specifying that the value 100 should be of the 64-bit 2's complement signed integer format, this will not fit within 32 bits without an overflow, which is why the compiler does not allow that assignment.